# F# (.. ..) operator usage/overloading

Tags: f#, operator-overloading

I'm interested in using/overloading the "range step" operator (.. ..), but I can't for the life of me find out how to use it.

In the documentation it says

```
// Usage:
start .. step .. finish
```

but trying that in the F# shell gives errors:

```
> let x = 1 .. 2 .. 7;;

  let x = 1 .. 2 .. 7;;
  ----------^^

stdin(54,11): error FS0010: Unexpected symbol '..' in binding. Expected incomplete structured construct at or before this point or other token.
```

However, calling it "explicitly" is possible:

```
> let x = (.. ..) 1 2 7;;

val x : seq<int>
```

Is it only possible to use this operator for list/seq construction such as `[1..2..7]` and `seq {1..2..7}`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [spec <sup>§ 6.3.12</sup>](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/cambridge/projects/fsharp/manual/spec.html#_Toc270597450) isn't explicit about it, but the only examples given are within sequence expressions. That, along with the fact that nothing else works, seems to confirm your conclusion.

FYI - Here are the relevant docs for the range operators.

[`Operators.( .. )<^T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee370568.aspx)
[`Operators.( .. .. )<^T,^Step>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee353647.aspx)

[Section 3.8.2](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/cambridge/projects/fsharp/manual/spec.html#_Toc270597393) also mentions special handling of `(.. ..)`, so it's safe to assume it's subject to limitations/behavior apart from those of typical functions/operators.

Comment: Marking this as the accepted answer since it was the fastest and all others didn't add more relevant information. Seems that `(.. ..)` can only live within `seq {...}`. -- Thanks for reading the spec for me ;-)

Answer (score 3):

**Overriding (.. ..) operator**

If you redefine `(.. ..)` operator as in @kvb's answer, it will override that operator of any type. Since you probably want to make `(.. ..)` operator work for a custom datatype, overriding static `(+)` and `One` members is enough. For example, here's a custom numeric type for modular arithmetic taken from [@Tomas's blog](http://tomasp.net/blog/fsharp-custom-numeric.aspx):

```
  type IntegerZ5 = 
   | Z5 of int
   member z.ToInt32() =  
     let (Z5 n) = z in n
   override z.ToString() = 
     sprintf "%d (mod 5)" (z.ToInt32())

   static member Create(n) = 
     let z5 = n % 5
     Z5(max ((z5 + 5) % 5) z5)
   static member (+) (Z5 a, Z5 b) = IntegerZ5.Create(a + b)
   static member (-) (Z5 a, Z5 b) = IntegerZ5.Create(a - b)
   static member (*) (Z5 a, Z5 b) = IntegerZ5.Create(a * b)
   static member Zero = Z5 0
   static member One  = Z5 1

  let inline z5 a = IntegerZ5.Create(a)
```

While constructing a range starting from the lower bound, `(+)` and `One` are used to find the next element. The construction finishes when the next element equals to or exceeds the range's upper bound. Now you can employ `IntegerZ5` in any range expression:

```
  let s1 = seq{z5 37..z5 3};; // seq [Z5 2; Z5 3]
  let s2 = seq{z5 10..z5 22..z5 4};; // seq [Z5 0; Z5 2; Z5 4]
```

**Using (.. ..) operator**

Another use of range expression is in `for` loops. I find it helpful in many cases:

```
let sum = 
    let mutable s = 0L
    for i in 1L..1000L do (* or 1L..1L..1000L with an explicit step *)
        s <- s + i
    s
```

because it is more flexible than `for...to..do` which is restricted to `int` only and implies a range with a step of `1`:

```
let sum = 
    let mutable s = 0L
    for i = 1L to 1000L do (* doesn't work *)
        s <- s + i
    s
```

Comment: That's a nice use, especially since, according to the spec, it's translated into a simple for loop in many cases.

Comment: ...and it works for range expressions with explicit step not equal to 1 as well, like in `for i in 1I..2I..100I do printf "%A " i`

Comment: Sure it does. That's why I said it's more flexible.

Answer (score 2):

The uses of this operator are covered by [section 6.3.12 of the spec](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/cambridge/projects/fsharp/manual/spec.html#_Toc270597450) (Range Expressions).  The built-in `(.. ..)` operator works on any type with appropriate `(+)` and `Zero` members, but you *can* redefine it to do something else (note that this example is nonsensical):

```
let (.. ..) x y z = 
    Seq.map (fun (s:string) -> s.[z] + y) x

let result = seq { ["test"; "func"] .. (char 1) .. 2 } // contains 't' 'o'
```